# Is there a pickup for Melodica?

Tags: guitar-effects, pick-ups, reeds, melodica

I've got a couple of [melodicas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melodica) I want to run through guitar pedals, especially distortion and wah and then run the signal into a guitar amp.

Is there some kind of pickup I can put in or attach to the melodica?  The pickup can't really be a transducer because transducers will squeal under distortion. It can't be an external mic because mics feedback and require a mic stand which makes the whole thing bulky as heck.

[image]

Comment: tape a lav mic to it - extreme example [DPA 4060](http://www.dpamicrophones.com/en/products.aspx?c=item&category=128&item=24035) [one of my favourite mics]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you may want to try a [piezo pickup](http://www.melodicas.com/melodica_pickup.htm) even though your comment about "transducers" seems to rule them out.

To my knowledge there is no equivalent to guitar pickups for free-reeeds, i.e. some type of pickup that transforms the mechanical motion of the metallic reed into an electrical signal (such a thing would seem to be possible for steel reeds, but wiring it up would be a mess).  Thus you'll aways be looking at a signal chain of reed->sound->microphone->amp.  Where microphone is either a normal external one (including lavaliere or clip on instrument microphone) or some sort of piezo/contact microphone.

Comment: Another problem with a piezo is that it will pickup up the thumping of the keys, probably even more than the reeds.